# How to show a even from a date range in flutter table_calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I am using the flutter **table_calendar** to show event, but the challenge is insted of showing a each a everyday as a specific event I want to show a date range. I have a **start date** and an **end date** what I want is to show event on ***each and everyday*** between the both.

This is my code:

```
   TableCalendar(
                // availableCalendarFormats: CalendarFormat.month,
                calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,

                firstDay: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)),
                
                lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
                
                focusedDay: snapshot["startDate"].toDate(),
                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                  titleCentered: true,
                ),
              ),
```

here ***snapshot["startate"]*** is the starting **DateTime()**. As I have mentioned I want to show a event on each day from the startdate to another end date.

Comment: did you ever have any luck with that? 
I am looking for a -free- calendar-like widget to display date ranges myself..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this 3 parameter to achieve date range.

`onRangeSelected`,`rangeStartDay`,`rangeEndDay`.

Please check this link
https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/range_example.dart